# BIOS can't detect drives

Tags: hard-drive, bios, cd-drive

As the title says, BIOS can't find any connected drives. To be specific, I have CD/DVD and HDD connected that worked just a moment ago.

I was trying to install an OS on the new HDD using a CD. The installation was stuck, and shortly after, I could hear a clicking noise (it sounded just like a clock's "tick-tock" sound).  Every time it sounded, a red light on my PC's case flashed (which signifies read/write, I guess).  After that, I forcibly shutdown the computer, and since then, no drives can be detected.

*Just to make this clear: the drive I was trying to install an OS on is not the drive I normally use. Neither of them can be detected.*

Comment: If it's laptop, disconnect PC from power, remove both batteries, the main one and BIOS(!!!), then press and hold power button at least for 30 seconds, if you have a time leave PC without batteries for a few hours to be make sure all capacitors discharged. If after such procedure hdd aren't come back then it something with hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if, after powering up your PC, you can hear the HDD start working.

- If not, then it looks like a PSU (power supply unit) problem. It does not deliver enough power to run the drivers, or it was fried when you were installing the OS.
- If the HDD spins up, then the problem is in the motherboard.

To be sure, do this:

1. Disconnect the PC from the power source for a few minutes.
2. Remove the CMOS battery from the motherboard for 10 minutes. This should reset all settings to default.
3. Return the battery into the motherboard and connect the PC to a power source.

If the problem was related with some temporary motherboard problem, it should work now.

If the drives are still undetected, remove them and check if they work with another PC.

- If they work there, your problem is in the motherboard.
- If the drives are also undetected in the other PC, then the drives are dead.

Comment: Drives are probably OK since the drive I mainly use was disconnected when the 
"incident" happened but it also can't be detected.

Comment: Ok, but still it is PSU versus motherboard. Only way to figure it out: connect another PSU, if works, then problem is solved. If not - then all is pointing on motherboard, SATA controller in particular. Do this disconection from power I have written about, sometimes motherboard can go wacky form power overcharge, and disconnectinfg it from power source for some time can do the trick and bring it back to senses.

Comment: Tried with taking out the battery but that doesn't help. I can't hear HDD spinning, there are no lights indicating that drives are working (like the red light in the question or the blinking light on the CD/DVD drive). I don't have another PSU right now but that's probably where the problem lies. I'll try it when I get one, though.

Comment: Accepting you answer since it's very helpful, but that didn't really solved it for me. All what was need is to switch IDE/PATA cables of the HDD and CD/DVD. I don't know why, but PC used to work just fine with gray one plugged in HDD and yellow one in CD/DVD, but now it works only vice versa. Any ideas why?

Comment: No idea. If it worked before, and now works in reverse order - should also worked in original configiuration. I understand that after you have tried  run it in vice versa,  you also have tried to go back to original configuraiont but still not working then? Anyway - no idea why this is happening. It should not - but it does. Computers:)

Comment: "I understand that after you have tried run it in vice versa, you also have tried to go back to original configuraiont but still not working then?" Yes.